# What are things we need to add on Build Settings in Xcode 7.0 projects?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

If we are adding frameworks using CocoaPods, It may cause some problems during compilation like (Not found Header search path, library search path & framework search path, Undefined architecture,etc.,)

What we need to do and what are things we need to add in Build settings. I'm very confusing on that.

I have mentioned below for Build Settings option.Can any one please explain me the below things. So many of them confused regarding that.

```
Architectures
Build Locations
Build Options
Code signing
Deployment
Headers
Linking
Search Paths
Apple LLVM 7.0 Preprocessing
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please refer this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

Comment: Thanks Badal. Hope it may help me..